# folder doesn't load while making the URLs work with and without the .php

Tags: .htaccess

I included the code for making the URLs work with and without `.php`. I included the below written code

```
   RewriteEngine On    
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Now the url works with and without `.php`. For e.g. if we put http://www.test.com/test.php or http://www.test.com/test both works. But the problem is folders doesn't load. For e.g. http://www.test.com/admin doesn't load. `not found error` is shown. Admin is a folder. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

just try this...I think its working

Answer (score 1):

Try below :

```
  RewriteEngine On    
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC,L]
```

this will also work with a directory path.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for .php extension removal instead:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

**Make sure to comment out your existing code**